# Are this auto executed functions? if yes, How do they work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code here in stackoverflow but I'm still asking to myself how exactly the timers auto start the fist time automatically.

However I noticed that commenting this:

```
 //Optionally, activate each timer:
 //restart(i)();
```

will prevent the timers to auto start.

It may be an auto executed function, and if it is. Will auto-executable functions always auto-start even though in this case the button is still not clicked?

An also I see that there are others that may be auto-executed functions inside functions, can somebody explain how this woks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>


<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Stop Timer" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Restart Timer" />
<span id="count0">0</span>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Stop Timer" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Restart Timer" />
<span id="count1">0</span>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment" />

<br />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Stop Timer" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Restart Timer" />
<span id="count2">0</span>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment" />

<br />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Stop Timer" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Restart Timer" />
<span id="count3">0</span>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment" />

<br />
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Stop Timer" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Restart Timer" />
<span id="count4">0</span>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment" />

<script>




    (function(){ //Anonymous function, to not leak variables to the global scope
        var defaultSpeed = 3000; //Used when missing
        var timerSpeed = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000];

        var intervals = [];



        function increase(i){
            return function(){
                var elem = $("#count"+i);
                elem.text(parseInt(elem.text()) + 1);
            }
        }
        function clear(i){
            return function(){
                clearInterval(intervals[i]);
            }
        }
        function restart(i){ //Start AND restart
            return function(){
                clear(i)();
                increase(i)();
                intervals[i] = setInterval(increase(i), timerSpeed[i]||defaultSpeed);
            }
        }




        // Manual increment
        $('input[name=increment]').each(function(i){
            $(this).click(function(){
                restart(i)();
                increase(i)();
            });
        });

        // Clear timer on "Clear"
        $('input[name=clear]').each(function(i) {
            $(this).click(clear(i));
        });

        // Restart timer on "Restart"
        $('input[name=reset]').each(function(i) {
            $(this).click(restart(i));

            //Optionally, activate each timer:
            restart(i)();
        });


    })();






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's easier to see what's going on if you change the comment from "//Optionally, activate each timer:" to "//Unconditionally, activate each timer:". The outer function is guaranteed to run (it's self executing), therefore (barring fatal errors) `$('input[name=reset]').each(function(i){..});` is guaranteed to run, therefore `restart(i)();` is guaranteed to run.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one self executing function in the code, it is the wrapping function at the top of the code (//Anonymous function, to not leak variables to the global scope).

Self executing function may have the format `(function(parameters){})(arguments list);`.

The functions like `restart` are not self executing functions, they are not invoked automatically, they are invoked manually. These functions are functions which returns another function, it is called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

So if you look at the statement `restart(i)();`, there are two things happening.
1. `restart(i)` returns a function 2. we are invoking the function using the second set of parenthesis.
For better under standing we can split this statement into two sections

```
var fn = restart(i);
fn();
```

**Update:**
The timers are auto started because of the following code

```
//Optionally, activate each timer:
restart(i)();
```

It will initiate the start each of the timer